# While loading data from a file php runs HTML code in the file. How to ignore it

Tags: php, html

One of my file is read by php and loaded on the Web UI. But if the file contains HTML tags, it interprets and disturbs the whole UI.
How to ignore the HTML tags while reading the file contents.

I am using following code to read file contents:
readfile($name);

Comment: It is the browser (client) who executes (render) HTML, not your php (server)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it ?

Comment: Is that what you wanted? Or you want to strip all html tags, and show values only?

Comment: My file contains the following:
#</textarea><script>alert("yoloyloyly")</script><textarea>
some string

Now I don't want the HTML code there to be interpreted. I tried strip_tags but that didn't work :(

Comment: Do you want the script to execute?

Comment: I tried strip_tags(file_get_contents($name)) and it worked. So, the issue was with readfile(), it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

e.g. `echo htmlspecialchars($stringFile);`

If you want to strip all html tags, check [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.